# How to get faster YAML loading in Ruby 1.8.7?

Tags: ruby, performance, serialization, yaml

In this Ruby 1.8.7 application, YAML deserializing (done with `YAML.load`) is needed because the existing data is stored in many relatively small YAML documents, but is a performance bottleneck.

Is there a way or a library that has this better? Upgrading to ruby 1.9 is not an option.

Comment: Are you using many of the special features in yaml (custom types, anchors, aliases) ? If not perhaps you can map your yaml documents int o JSON and then parse the json. Sounds hacky though

Comment: No special features. That's an interesting idea.

Comment: You've checked that CPU, not I/O, is the bottleneck, right?

Comment: Yes, because I've timed only the `YAML.load` calls where the argument passed is a string already loaded in memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't find a way to do this. I've tried converting YAML to JSON via string manipulation, then parsing that with fast JSON parsers such as Yajl and OJ, but the overhead of converting YAML to JSON was already longer than actually parsing YAML.

My conversion script probably wasn't as fast as it could be if someone smart really dedicated a lot of time to do this, but I gave up on this early after I realized even if I optimize my own script, it still wouldn't beat YAML parsing time significantly enough to warrant the whole approach.

Answer (score 2):

I am not an expert but if it's possible for you to convert the YAML documents to Marshal documents and then use `Marshal.load` afterwards in the application, it should be much faster. I used [this gist](https://gist.github.com/480059) a while back to compare YAML vs Marshal performance.

Comment: Some more benchmarks which also show `Marshal` is significantly faster: http://blog.carlmercier.com/2010/11/19/yaml-zaml-marshal-json-benchmark-in-ruby/ and http://significantbits.wordpress.com/2008/01/29/yaml-vs-marshal-performance/

Comment: I should have stressed that out, but I'm not able to change existing documents. If I was, I would choose a faster serialization format such as Marshal or probably JSON.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this experiment](http://blog.carlmercier.com/2010/11/19/yaml-zaml-marshal-json-benchmark-in-ruby/), using ZAML under 1.8.7 will be faster than the YAML parser.

Comment: ZAML only provides the `dump` method, while I'm only interested in the `load` method.